# How to have this textbox display a different page in browser after the first time it's clicked (winforms C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button on this Winforms app that when clicked, displays an HTML file in the browser module.

I need the button to display one file when it is clicked the first time and a different file any other time after that.

Here's the code that makes it open the first file:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/mail/index.html", curDir));
        }
```

Currently it displays `file:///{0}/mail/index.html` every time it is clicked. I want it to display `file:///{0}/mail/index2.html` for the second and every other time it is clicked. How would I go about structuring this? is there an event that only responds to the first action on a piece of code? I've looked online for a while and can't seem to find anything specific to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event that only responds to the first action (you could theoretically create it yourself though). But it is much simpler to have just one `Click` event and inside it's event handler decide, which file to show - depending on  value of boolean variable that "remembers" if it is first button click or not. Something like this:

```
// Private filed of form that keeps track of whether button was already clicked before or not
private bool IsFirstButtonClick = true;

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

    // Display appropriate file depending on whether it is first time button click or not
    if(IsFirstButtonClick)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/mail/index.html", curDir));

        // Set flag so that next time button is clicked, we know it was alredy clicked (at least once) before
        IsFirstButtonClick = false;
    }
    else
        this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/mail/index2.html", curDir));
}
```